# How can we map a c# complex list object from FormData in MVC through Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, multipartform-data, form-data

I have a list object in my controller. I need to map this List object with the data which is getting passed to controller in an Ajax call from FormData. The reason why i am using FormData is, i need to get some files from the view in this same ajax call.

Please find my code below

```
 public class AdModel
{
    public PartsAd PartsAdModel { get; set; }
    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> AdImages { get; set; }
}
public class PartsAd
{
    public List<Vehicle> VehicleList { get; set; }
}
public class Vehicle
{
    public string VehicleBrand { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my action method in controller

```
 public ActionResult AjaxPostAd(AdModel adModel)
    {
    }
```

Below is my Jquery Code

```
var applicableVehicleBrands = $('#multiSelectApplicableVehicleBrand option:selected');
    var selectedBrand = 0;
    $(applicableVehicleBrands).each(function () {
        data.append("adModel[PartsAdModel.VehicleList[" + selectedBrand + "].VehicleBrand]", $(this).val())
        selectedBrand = selectedBrand + 1;
    });
 $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "post",
    async: true,
    url: "" + ajaxPostURL + "",
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {});
```

But in my controller, when i look for adModel.PartsAdModel.VehicleList, it is null

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For model binding to work, your form data should have properties with this name

```
PartsAdModel.VehicleList[{n}].VehicleBrand
```

Where `{n}` is the zero based index of the array of vehicle items you want to send.

You do not need the `adModel` prefix in the formd data item name as model binder will not care about the parameter name you use in your HttpPost action method.

The below code should work. I just hard coded 2 items for the `VehicleList` property. You may update it so that it dynamically add item (in a loop) based on your DOM inputs.

```
var data = new FormData();

data.append("PartsAdModel.VehicleList[0].VehicleBrand", "Honda");
data.append("PartsAdModel.VehicleList[1].VehicleBrand", "Toyota");

// Add the uploaded file
// Assuming you have a file input with name="AdImages"
$('input[name="AdImages"]').each(function(a, b) {
    var fileInput = $('input[name="AdImages"]')[a];
    if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        data.append("AdImages", file);
    }
});


$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: '@Url.Action("AjaxPostAd")',
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
}).done(function(r) {
    console.log('ajax call done');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shyju for this Quick Answer. The adModel prefix in the formdata was causing the issue for me. Its working fine, when i removed it.